# Editar filas con php

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Recién hago una tabla de usuarios con las funciones de eliminar, editar y agregar, yo tengo las funciones de agregar, eliminar y editar, el problema es cuando le doy editar a una fila me aparecen los campos de la fila con el id=1, esto en cualquier fila, y lo que quiero es que cuando le de click en la fila con el id=5 me aparezcan los datos con ese id y asi dependiendo de la fila aparezcan los datos  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código index.php

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FOTO</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>APELLIDO</th>
            <th>TELEFONO</th>
            <th>DIRECCION</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
<tbody>
 <?php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Foto']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Nombre'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Apellido'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Telefono'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Direccion'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' ><a href='eliminar.php?id=".$row["id"]."'>Eliminar</a></button>"?></td>
        <td>
       <div class="container">
           <?php echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" id=' . $row['id'] . '" >Editar</button>' ?>
             <!--<?php /*echo *///'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" id=' . $row['id'] . '" >Editar</button>' ?>-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <fieldset style="width:400px">
                                    <form action=" " method="post" emctype="multipart/form data">
                                        <table class="table">

                                            <!--<tr>
                                                <td><label for="id">Id:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id" value='<?php// echo $row//['id'];?>'></td>
                                            </tr>-->

                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="nombre">Foto:</label></td>
                                                <td><input name="myFile" type="file" value='<?php echo $row['Foto'];?>' ></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="email">Nombre:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value='<?php echo  $row['Nombre'] ;?>'></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="Apellido">Apellido:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" value='<?php echo $row['Apellido'];?>'/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="Telefono">Telefono:</label></td>
                                                <td><input id="telNo" name="telNo" type="tel" value='<?php echo $row['Telefono'];?>' /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr> 
                                                <td><label for="Direccion">Direccion:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" value='<?php echo $row['Direccion'];?>'/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="Email">Email:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email"  value='<?php echo $row['Email'];?>'/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                <button id="actualizar" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </fieldset>   
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

y aquí está el código edit.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $con = dbConnect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE id = '$id'";
?>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes colocar la tabla dentro de un form de modo que el id lo crees dentro de un input hidden y al pulsar edit envies el form a editar.php donde obtendrás el id y podrás realizar las operaciones para mostrar el formulario de edición, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Debes especificar qué Modal debes abrir al dar clic en el botón "Editar". En este caso debes agregar el id en el atributo "data-target"

```
<?php echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_' . $row['id'] . '" id=' . $row['id'] . '" >Editar</button>' ?>
```

Y debes agregar un id unico a cada Modal dentro de tu div.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal_<?= $row['id']; ?>" role="dialog">
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: el problema es que despues de agregarle el id a unico a cada modal, el boton de editar pierde su función y no hace nada

Comment: Verifica que los IDs tanto del modal como del botón si correspondan. Ejemplo: data-target="#Modal_16" id="Modal_16"

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" role="dialog">
```

Estas generando todos los modales con la misma id.  Las ids deben de ser unicas.  Cuando presionas el boton, va a mostrar la primera instancia de ese id, que es la fila uno.  La solucion es darle ids unicos a cada modal como hiciste con los botones.